# How to run an external filter on a part of a line?

Tags: filter

How do I run an external filtering program on a part of a line?

When I do:

`:'<,'>!myfilter`

it always filters the whole line regardless of whether the whole line is selected or just a part of it.

Comment: you can't since ex commands are by default linewise. Easiest way is to copy the line and remove the parts that you do not want to filter. Alternatively, using a plugin like my NarrowRegion plugin may help.

Comment: As Christian says, `:!` and other ex commands work line-by-line, so it filters the whole lone. You cant change this behavior, but you can do workarounds... a good answer will demonstrate such workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 :s/\%V.*\%V./\=system('myfilter', submatch(0))[:-2]/
```

---

As an example, consider this text:

```
one  zwei three
four fünf six
```

Visually select the block containing the german numbers `zwei` and `fünf`, and run this command:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V./\=system('trans -brief', submatch(0))[:-2]/
```

It should translate the numbers into english:

```
one  two three
four five six
```

[image: filter visual block to translate german numbers into english]

*Requires the shell utility [`translate-shell`](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell).*

---

To make the process a little easier, you could install this mapping:

```
xno <c-g>s :s/\%V.*\%V./\=system('', submatch(0))[:-2]/<c-r>=setcmdpos(28)[-1]<cr>
```

Press `C-g s` while selecting your text. It should populate the command-line with:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V./\=system('', submatch(0))[:-2]/
                            ^
                            cursor right before
```

And the cursor should be correctly positioned to let you immediately type the name of the filter you want to use.

---

For more info, see:

```
:h /\%V
:h system()
:h submatch()
:h setcmdpos()
```