# Vim filter command not using line-wise selection

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, cut-copy-paste, filter

I may have seen this question before on Vi Exchange but I'm having trouble locating it while searching now. If it's already been answered, please let me know the duplicate and I can find that.

I have text like this:

[image]

And I would like to copy that text to the clipboard. The command I'm using is:

```
:'<,'>w !it2copy
```

However, it seems to do a line-wise copy (as if I am in Visual-Line mode), as the clipboard now shows:

```
my_string = """SELECT * FROM
mytable WHERE id=4"""
```

Instead of, what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM
mytable WHERE id=4
```

How can I get the exact cursor selection instead of the line-wise equivalent?

Note that an answer should take the copy-paste across multiple-lines into account.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24976/17449

Comment: If you don't want to filter the text, pass the `n` flag to `:s` so that it doesn't substitute the selection.

Comment: @user938271 hmm...I don't think that answer would work on the following though where it passes the output to the clipboard. For example: `:s/\%V.*\%V./\=system('it2copy', submatch(0))[:-2]/n`. Also it only seems to match on one line (not all lines).

Comment: How about yanking the visual selection in the unnamed register, then writing it into the clipboard with `call system('it2copy', @")`?

Comment: @user938271 it is almost like we would need to do a function to get the line number...delete whatever position comes before the first line col and after the last line col; do the copy; then undo the previous change.

Comment: @user938271 it's an ssh'd vim session and so I need to use `it2copy` (it's an extension from iTerm2) to copy to my local clipboard...the whole thing is a bit hacky, but trying to figure out the last step... By that I mean yanking from `"` or `*` or `+` don't work as usual on the remote host.

Comment: Not sure why you can't yank the text in the unnamed register, then write it on the stdin of `it2clip` via `system()`, but, fwiw, I have [a mapping](https://github.com/lacygoill/config/blob/fc88f0e46786ac2403cccdc36212e34973a29c0e/.vim/vimrc#L8432-L8474) which leverages the sequence OSC 52 for this kind of situations.  It relies on [this script](https://github.com/lacygoill/config/blob/master/bin/sendtoclipboard).

Comment: @user938271 holy cow, a 10k line vim settings file?!

Comment: @David542 A *very well documented* 10k line vimrc file!!! :-D

Answer (score 2):

To apply Ex command to an arbitrary selection you can do the following:

1. Copy selection to the end of file
2. Select those new lines and run the command
3. Cut the result
4. Replace old selection with the result

Of course, it's no good in doing this manually, so the plugins exist.

I know of [VIS](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vis) (written by DrChip), and [vim-opera](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-opera) (that one is mine; it also provides an easy-to-use interface for `g@` operator). Probably, there must be others too.